# Why has the textfile's encoding changed from UTF-8 to ANSI (and how to solve this)?

Tags: android, text-files, email-attachments, indy10, delphi-xe8

I'm sending a .txt file as an attachment from an Android device using Indy.

When I download this, the .txt file's encoding has changed from UTF-8 to ANSI and is displaying it's content in lines next to eachother instead of underneath eachother.

So what have I been doing wrong, and how to solve this?

Functional code used to send the mail:

```
Body := TStringList.Create;
IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
SSLHandler:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Form1);
IdSMTP.IOHandler:= SSLHandler;
IdSMTP.UseTLS:= utUseExplicitTLS;

IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
IdSMTP.Port := 587;
IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
IdSMTP.Username := AppData.MailAddrSender;
IdSMTP.Password := Appdata.MailPassword;

IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
IdMessage.From.Name := aName;
IdMessage.From.Address := AppData.MailAddrSender;
IdMessage.Subject := 'E-mail subject';

PathString := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, (PathString + 'Log.txt'));
Body.Add('Mail todays log,');
if FileExists(PathString) then
  TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts,PathString);
try
  for I := 0 to Body.Count -1 do
    IdMessage.Body.Add(Body.Strings[I]);
  IdEmailAddressItem := IdMessage.Recipients.Add;
  IdEmailAddressItem.Address := AppData.MailAddrReceiver;

  try
    IdSMTP.Connect;
    try
      if IdSMTP.Authenticate then
      IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);

    finally
      IdMessage.Free;
      IdSMTP.Disconnect;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
    //exception handling here
  end;
finally
  IdSMTP.Free;
  SSLHandler.DisposeOf;
  Body.DisposeOf;
end;
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I download this, the .txt file's encoding has changed from UTF-8 to ANSI

When using `TIdAttachmentFile`, the raw bytes of the file are sent as-is.  Indy does not change an attached file's encoding.

`TIdAttachmentFile` defaults its `ContentType` property value based on the extension of the filename that you pass to the constructor.  In this case, the extension is `.txt` so the `ContentType` should be defaulting to `text/plain`.  The `text/...` media type has a `charset` attribute associated with it, but you are not setting the attachment's `Charset` property in your code.  Without that, the recipient will interpret the data using a default `charset` instead (typically `us-ascii` per RFC 822).  So it is likely that the recipient is detecting the `text/plain` media type with a missing `charset` and is *displaying* the file data in ASCII/ANSI because it does not know the data is actually UTF-8 encoded instead (since the file is an attachment, the recipient should be *saving* the raw bytes as-is if saving the attachment to a new file).

If you know for a fact that the file you are attaching is encoded in UTF-8, you should be explicit about it:

```
if FileExists(PathString) then
begin
  Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, PathString);
  Attachment.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  Attachment.Charset := 'utf-8';
end;
```

> and is displaying it's content in lines next to eachother instead of underneath eachother.

That sounds more like a linebreak issue than an encoding issue.  For instance, if the original file on Android is using `LF` linebreaks, but the recipient only supports `CRLF` linebreaks instead.

If you want, you can have Indy normalize the linebreaks to `CRLF`.  You would simply load the file data into a `TIdText` instead of a `TIdAttachmentFile`, and then be sure to set the `TIdText.ContentDisposition` property to `attachment` (otherwise it will default to `inline`), and set the `TIdText.FileName`, so the data is still treated as an attachment by the recipient:

```
if FileExists(PathString) then
begin
  Attachment := TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
  Attachment.Body.LoadFromFile(PathString, TEncoding.UTF8);
  Attachment.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  Attachment.Charset := 'utf-8';
  Attachment.ContentDisposition := 'attachment';
  Attachment.FileName := ExtractFileName(PathString);
end;
```

Now, with all of that said, there are some other minor coding issues with your use of Indy's components in general.  I would suggest something more like this instead:

```
try
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTP);
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port := 587;
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.Username := AppData.MailAddrSender;
    IdSMTP.Password := Appdata.MailPassword;

    IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
      IdMessage.From.Name := aName;
      IdMessage.From.Address := AppData.MailAddrSender;
      IdMessage.Subject := 'E-mail subject';

      IdEmailAddressItem := IdMessage.Recipients.Add;
      IdEmailAddressItem.Address := AppData.MailAddrReceiver;

      IdMessage.Body.Add('Mail todays log,');

      PathString := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, PathString + 'Log.txt');
      if FileExists(PathString) then
      begin
        // or TIdText...
        Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, PathString);
        Attachment.ContentType := 'text/plain';
        Attachment.Charset := 'utf-8';
      end;

      IdSMTP.Connect;
      try
        IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
      finally
        IdSMTP.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      IdMessage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdSMTP.Free;
  end;
except
  on E: Exception do
    //exception handling here
end;
```

Comment: I finally got this to working, thank you very much for the elaborated answer and the coding suggestion!